# capybara: fill in form field value with terminating enter key

Tags: capybara

I'm testing a barcode reader input... it behaves like the keyboard but terminates each barcode with the enter key character. My javascript detects the enter key and responds (backbone.js application).

How can I "fill in" a form field with a string that has a terminating enter key value?

My test stack is cucumber/capybara/capybara-webkit.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it seems that you can just send a **\n** to capybara's native set method and achieve the same effect (in a more flexible, driver agnostic way).

So in my code, this is currently working to trigger a form submit event (handled by JS):

```
  field = find("form input[type=text]")
  field.set "my comment\n"
```

(Note that, as the author of the pull request explains [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/12/better-key-events-in-capybara-webkit/#comment-15187), this only works if you're binding to the specific keydown event, not if you're binding to the form submit that should result from it.)

Comment: Not quite driver agnostic - depends how the driver implements form entry. For example, poltergeist only called a change event not too long ago, rather than keydown and the lot. ([See this ticket](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/43))

For me, this worked in selenium and not poltergeist, I am checking keypress events for `e.keycode == 13`

Comment: This didn't work for me in Poltergeist either. Debugging it, it looks like the dispatched keypress events always have `e.which == 0`, which is apparently due to a bug in WebKit that's been around forever and gets almost no attention https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16735

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `Capybara::Driver::Selenium` as your page driver for that particular scenario. If you do then you can do things like this:

```
place = page.find_by_id('tinymce').native
place.send_keys("I rule!")
place.send_key "\xEE\x80\x83"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I had already done this successfully in Selenium, although not as concisely as your suggestion. But I was trying to speed up my tests with capybara-webkit.

Comment: You can manage your scenarios and drivers using tags. For example you can configure your system, so any scenario tagged @selenium is being run using Selenium driver. This way you can get speed of webkit driver in most of your scenarios and use selenium for problematic ones. Good luck :)