# Is there a way to send key presses to Webkit using Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webkit, capybara, keypress

I need to send some key-presses to a web app in an integration test that uses Capybara and WebKit. Using Selenium (WebDriver and Firefox) I can achieve it like this:

```
find("#element_id").native.send_keys :tab
```

but WebKit's native element node doesn't have a send_keys method. Actually native in WebKit returned a string containing a number. Is there another way to send keystrokes to WebKit? Maybe even some workaround using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this Pablo?  I still have the same issue you originally had with .native method.  Just returns '4' for example.

Answer (score 18):

I've been trying to implement Marc's answer without any success, but I found some help from a similar question: [capybara: fill in form field value with terminating enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866469/capybara-fill-in-form-field-value-with-terminating-enter-key).  And apparently there was a [pull request](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/12/better-key-events-in-capybara-webkit/#comment-15187) from capybara that seems to address this issue.

What worked for me was:

```
before { fill_in "some_field_id", with: "\t" }
```

My example erases the text in the field and then presses <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  To fill in a field with `'foobar'`, replace `"\t"` with `"foobar\t"`.  You can also use `"\n"` for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

For your example, you could use:

```
find("#element_id").set("\t")
```

Comment: I confirm that `find("#label").set(my_label + "\n")` triggers the `Enter` key.

Comment: Thanks man! Worked for me. I was really suprised of such simple solution!

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me with Poltergeist, to trigger the asterisk key:

```
find("body").native.send_key("*")
```

I had no luck with the other solutions; not even Syn.

This was to trigger an [angular-hotkeys](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/) event.

Comment: Yet another reason to use Poltergeist. It just makes life easier. This worked for me with zero friction.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like that:

```
keypress_script = "var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: #{keycode} }); $('body').trigger(e);"
page.driver.browser.execute_script(keypress_script)
```

Comment: This worked for me. We're actually using the poltergeist driver (PhantomJS) instead of Capybara WebKit, so I had to make a minor change to the 2nd line of code there:
page.driver.execute_script(keypress_script)

Comment: This worked for me, but I should use page.execute_script(keypress_script).

Comment: FYI - Poltergeist supports element.native.send_keys(*keys)

Answer (score 6):

Now since Capybara-webkit 1.9.0 you can send key presses like enter and others using send_keys:

```
find("textarea#comment").send_keys(:enter)
```

Source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/191#issuecomment-228758761

Capybara API Docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Asend_keys

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing the following:

```
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
keypress_script = "$('input#my_field').val('some string').keydown();"
page.driver.browser.execute_script(keypress_script)
```

I discovered in Chrome, testing my JavaScript, that actually creating an `$.Event` with `keyCode` or `charCode` and then triggering that on my input field didn't put the characters in the input.  I was testing autocompletion which required a few characters be in the input field, and it would start the autocompletion on `keydown`.  So I set the input value manually with `val`, then trigger `keydown` to cause the autocompletion script to start.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, triggering a `keypress` event in JS will work:

```
def press(code)
  page.execute_script("$('#my-input').trigger($.Event('keypress', {keyCode: #{code}}))")
end
```

For a more general and robust answer, use this [great library](https://github.com/bitovi/syn) that goes through the trouble of triggering the right events (i.e. `keydown`, then `keypress` and finally `keyup`).

```
def type(string)
  page.execute_script("Syn.click({}, 'my-input').wait().type(#{string.to_json})")
end
```

A more complex example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371911/capybara-integration-tests-with-jquery-selectize/23371912#23371912)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which works with capybara `2.1.0`:

```
fill_in('token-input-machine_tag_list', :with => 'new tag name')
page.evaluate_script("var e = $.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 13 }); $('#token-input-machine_tag_list').trigger(e);") # Press enter
```

Please, note, that in new capybara you have to use `page.evaluate_script`.

Answer (score 0):

For Capybara Webkit, this is the solution I used:

```
def press_enter(input)
  script = "var e = jQuery.Event('keypress');"
  script += "e.which = 13;"
  script += "$('#{input}').trigger(e);"
  page.execute_script(script);
end
```

Then I use it cleanly in my test like:

```
press_enter("textarea#comment")
```