# alternative to find_field('doc-name').native.send_keys(:tab) in capybara-webkit

Tags: webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit

the :selenium driver in capybara allowed me to write:

`find_field('doc-name').native.send_keys(:tab)`

is there an equivalent construct with the :webkit driver?

I am trying to tab away from a field, which causes some AJAX validation to happen and then proceed to the next step in my test file. I am getting the following error with capybara-webkit:

`undefined method`send_keys' for "20":String`

I am using:

```
jruby (1.6.7)
capybara (1.1.2)
capybara-webkit (0.13.0)
cucumber (1.1.0)
cucumber-rails2 (0.3.5)
factory_girl (1.2.4)
gherkin (2.5.4)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
rspec (1.3.2)
rspec-rails (1.3.4)
trinidad (1.3.5)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to send key presses to Webkit using Capybara?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474103/is-there-a-way-to-send-key-presses-to-webkit-using-capybara)

Answer (score 0):

Capybara now supports `send_keys` like this:

```
element = page.find("#my_element")
element.send_keys(:space)
```

The only supported keystrokes are Space, Enter, and Backspace, though.

I also find it pretty unreliable (fails every other time).

Source:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/lib/capybara/webkit/node.rb#L50-L65