# In Capybara, how to fill in a field with a text containing a tab?

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

Each of my scenarios reads a sample in a file and copy them in a text field:

```
def sample(name)
  IO.read("spec/samples/#{name}.bib")
end

feature 'Import a record' do

  scenario 'from JabRef' do
    fill_in 'bibtex', :with => sample('jabref')
    in_dialog.click_button 'Import'
    ...
  end

end
```

This worked fine, until one of the sample had a tabulation in it: while a manual copy and paste worked, the test failed.

From other questions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474103/is-there-a-way-to-send-key-presses-to-webkit-using-capybara#answer-12809109)], I have understood that interpreting `\t` and `\n` as keyed inputs is supposed to be a "feature". Is there a way to deactivate this feature and just "paste" the content?

Comment: In the text field on the browser if you press your Tab key does it switch to another field?
Inserting a literal tab is a known pain in text fields, does [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/67934/typing-the-tab-character-in-browser-text-boxes) help?

Comment: @alex.frost My problem is that `fill_in` emulates typing rather than pasting. I would definitely prefer that users don't paste tabs in the field. However, some did and will probably do it again. I fixed the software to handle this, and now I would like to have a Capybara regression test for this.

Comment: Ok, its a long shot but maybe convert the "\t" to "\u0009" in ruby.  That is unicode for the tab character.  Also have you tried making it as simple as possible so: `fill_in 'bibtex', :with => "text with \u0009 tab in"` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added `.gsub("\t", "\u0009")` after `IO.read`. My other samples are still OK, but the sample with the tab still fails. If I change it with `.gsub("\t", "   ")`, the test passes but it's a totally different test. I'm afraid that `s.gsub("\t", "\u0009")` has the same exact value as `s`.

Comment: If you use Selenium as a capybara driver please try `find(locator).native.send_keys Selenium::Webdriver::Keys[:tab]` instead of `fill_in locator, with: "\t"`

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Thanks for your suggestion but I use webkit driver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you could insert your text using [Javascript](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#scripting):

```
page.execute_script '$("#bibtex").val("' << sample('jabref') << '")'
```

If you do this often enough, I'd extract this in a helper method (`fill_in_plain` or similar), maybe without using the help of jQuery (using plain old Javascript, i.e. `document.getElementById` et cetera).

---

Here's a proper helper, still using jQuery:

```
module CapybaraWebkitWorkarounds

  def fill_in_plain(selector, with: nil)
    value = with.gsub '"', "\\\"" # poor man's escaping
    page.execute_script %Q{ $("#{selector}").val("#{value}") }
  end

end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # make it available in all feature specs
  config.include CapybaraWebkitWorkarounds, type: :feature
end
```

Then, in your feature spec, you'll do simply

```
feature 'Import a record' do

  scenario 'from JabRef' do
    fill_in_plain 'textarea[name="bibtex"]', with: sample('jabref')
    in_dialog.click_button 'Import'
    ...
  end

end
```

Please note, that the `fill_in_plain` helper now only understands jQuery selector (i.e. CSS selectors) strings as its first argument.